# Is there a way in crossfilter to create a multi-line plot where both the x and y values are the result of a group?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have data set that looks like the below:

```
var livingThings = crossfilter([
  { rate: 0.14, animal: "cat", months: 1, trial: "A"},
  { rate: 0.77, animal: "cat", months: 1, trial: "B"},
  { rate: 0.71, animal: "cat", months: 1, trial: "C"},
  { rate: 0.99, animal: "cat", months: 2, trial: "A"},
  { rate: 0.66, animal: "cat", months: 2, trial: "B"},
  { rate: 0.14, animal: "cat", months: 2, trial: "C"},
  { rate: 0.78, animal: "cat", months: 3, trial: "A"},
  { rate: 0.84, animal: "cat", months: 3, trial: "B"},
  { rate: 0.30, animal: "cat", months: 3, trial: "C"},
  { rate: 0.47, animal: "dog", months: 1, trial: "A"},
  { rate: 0.69, animal: "dog", months: 1, trial: "B"},
  { rate: 0.80, animal: "dog", months: 1, trial: "C"},
  { rate: 0.88, animal: "dog", months: 2, trial: "A"},
  { rate: 0.38, animal: "dog", months: 2, trial: "B"},
  { rate: 0.76, animal: "dog", months: 2, trial: "C"},
  { rate: 0.15, animal: "dog", months: 3, trial: "A"},
  { rate: 0.24, animal: "dog", months: 3, trial: "B"},
  { rate: 0.75, animal: "dog", months: 3, trial: "C"}
]);

ndx = crossfilter(livingThings);
```

I want to create a chart, using DC, that displays a line for each animal, where the y-value represents the median rate and the x-value the months. For example, the plot below was generated for the given dataset using python:

[image: graph from python]

This is for a dashboard that would also contain, for example, a pie chart for the trial dimension that would allow filtering of the line chart.

I've tried everything I can think of but can't quite manage it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the [series chart](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html)? A common point of confusion is that the stacked charts and the series charts have very different interfaces. This is unfortunate but it's just the way things are.

Comment: I tried with the line, composit and series charts but still couldn't figure it out

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I just linked to an example, does it help?